# Real-time data plotting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am building a web interface where I need to plot results in real-time. I am getting data from an API where I push events every one second. Do I need to worry about the front end ?

I am waiting 1 second everytime and call ajax again, is this a good way to do it ?

```
  function get_data() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/data',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: test
    });
  }

  function test(data) {

$('#testing').append('<p>'+data+'<p>');.

    setTimeout(get_data, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: You should use Websockets, which have less overhead

Comment: But they are only supported in modern browser, you could use socket.io, these library uses ajax in case websockets aren't supported

Comment: What about server sent event ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Comment: so what's the architechture that you advise, I am confrotable using node or python ?

Comment: @user3378649: What you use on the server side does not make any difference to the client

Comment: Most real-time mechanisms on the web have pros and cons. WebSockets do not have full support just yet, Flash is on the way out so raw TCP connections are not very reliable, HTTP requests/long polling is clunky and not as fast as they could be (although they may be fast enough, depending on your needs). I would recommend using WebSockets with a fallback library in case they are not suppored. You should also be aware of Web Workers if you  are processing a lot of data.